# Apache cordova (Phonegap) listening stream in aplication

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, phonegap-plugins, html5-audio

Is it possible in apache cordova phonegap listening radio station for example one of four solution:

```
radio.station.com:9988/listen.pls
radio.station.com:9988/listen.ram
radio.station.com:9988/listen.qtl
radio.station.com:9988/listen.asx
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to stream audio in iOS and Android via Apache/Cordova, [this plugin](https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media) might be what you are looking for.

Just do:

`window.plugins.streamingMedia.playAudio(audioUrl);`